# Problem plotting single and double column data with a boxplot

Tags: python

I am trying to plot columns of data form a .csv file in a boxplot/violin plot using matplotlib.pyplot.

When setting the dataframe [df] to one column of data, the plotting works fine.  However once I try to plot two columns I do not get a plot generated, and the code seems like it's just running and running, so I think there is something to how I am passing along the data.  Each columns is 54,500 row long.

```
 import os
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import seaborn as sns
 import pandas as pd
 from pandas import read_csv
 os.chdir(r"some_directory//")

 df = read_csv(r"csv_file.csv")
 # the csv file is 7 columns x 54500 rows, only concerned with two columns

 df = df[['surge', 'sway']]

 # re-size the dataframe to only use two columns
 data = df[['surge', 'sway']]


 #print data to just to confirm 
 print(data)


 plt.violinplot(data, vert=True, showmeans=True, showmedians=True)
 plt.show()
```

If I change the data line to data = df['surge'] I get a perfect plot with the 54501 surge values.

When I introduce the second variable as data = df[['surge', 'sway']] is when the program gets hung up.  I should note the same problem exists if I let data = df[['surge']] so I think it's something to do with the double braces and going from a list to an array, perhaps?